# Need help. Message says temp table doesn't exist: 'Invalid object name '#TempCodes'.'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

If I run the select statement below by itself (with the table name hard coded in) it runs fine and the temp table is created. If I run it as below it says 'Invalid object name '#TempCodes'' although when I print @Sql1 it looks exactly the same as when I run it by itself (with the table name hard coded in).

Any ideas on what's going on here will be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = '[My Table Name]'
DECLARE @Sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql1 = N'SELECT  AccountNumber,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value(''.[1]'',''varchar(8000)''))) AS mdcodes INTO #TempCodes FROM (SELECT AccountNumber,CAST(''<XMLRoot><RowData>''
    + REPLACE(MD_Results,'','',''</RowData><RowData>'') 
    + ''</RowData></XMLRoot>'' AS XML) AS x FROM  ' + @TableName 
    + N')t CROSS APPLY x.nodes(''/XMLRoot/RowData'')m(n)'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempCodes', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
   drop table  #TempCodes
END 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql1
Select * from #TempCodes
```

Comment: I bet you can create a Minimal Version of your code to make the question focus only on the problem. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess in tag you mean `sql-server` not `server` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a global temp table `##TempCodes` as local temporary tables are only visible in current session.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = '[My Table Name]'
DECLARE @Sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql1 = N'SELECT  AccountNumber,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value(''.
[1]'',''varchar(8000)''))) AS mdcodes INTO ##TempCodes FROM (SELECT 
AccountNumber,CAST(''<XMLRoot><RowData>'' + 
REPLACE(MD_Results,'','',''</RowData><RowData>'') + ''</RowData></XMLRoot>'' 
AS XML) AS x FROM  '+@TableName+ N')t CROSS APPLY 
x.nodes(''/XMLRoot/RowData'')m(n)'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##TempCodes', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
            BEGIN
            drop table  ##TempCodes
            END 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql1

Select * from ##TempCodes
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Remember accept the answer as correct using the green tick. Also for reference, this is what I mean with Minimal, Complete and Verifiable: http://rextester.com/OVLG5995

Comment: Most SQL code needs to be concurrent. Most not all. This solution has a high potential of breaking in a concurrent situation.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance In that case the problem is with the OP question, not with the answer provided by VDK. Because this answer actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `##` is a typo. Even if you fix it to `#` it will throw same error.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql1
```

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished.

In your case `sp_executesql` is the stored procedure.

the table created inside the dynamic query will be dropped after the `exec sp_executesql` is completed. That's why you are getting that error.

You need to create table outside and use `Insert into table..select` syntax inside the dynamic query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempCodes', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
   drop table  #TempCodes

create table #TempCodes(AccountNumber varchar(100),mdcodes varchar(100))

SET @Sql1 = N'Insert into #TempCodes
              SELECT  AccountNumber,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value(''.
[1]'',''varchar(8000)''))) AS mdcodes FROM (SELECT 
AccountNumber,CAST(''<XMLRoot><RowData>'' + 
REPLACE(MD_Results,'','',''</RowData><RowData>'') + ''</RowData></XMLRoot>'' 
AS XML) AS x FROM  '+@TableName+ N')t CROSS APPLY 
x.nodes(''/XMLRoot/RowData'')m(n)'
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, because I did a test case and I can access the temporal table after the sp_executesql when change `#` for `##`. Check this http://rextester.com/OVLG5995

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -  I was explaining for temporary table.. not for global temp table.. Trying changing it to #temp table in your code. It will fail